# How to get callback on sound completion

Tags: xcode

How to get callback on sound completion

Hello all, Im hoping someone can help me on using callback blocks
I am using Nick Lockwood's Soundmanager class for controlling sound playback in my app
https://github.com/nicklockwood/SoundManager

Ive tried this I know its wrong but I don't understand how to link the completion handler to a specific sound

```
 -(void)playSound
 {
    [[SoundManager sharedManager] playSound:@"Pop.caf" looping:NO];
    if (SoundDidFinishPlayingNotification) {
    soundNamed.completionHandler(YES);

}
```

}

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `SoundManager`'s `completionHandler` property:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) SoundCompletionHandler completionHandler;
```

> A callback block that will be called when the sound finishes playing,
>   or is stopped. Only one `completionHandler` block can be set on any
>   given `Sound` instance, but if you need multiple objects to track the
>   `Sound`'s status, you can add observers for the
>   `SoundDidFinishPlayingNotification` notification instead.

As stated above you can also listen for `SoundDidFinishPlayingNotification` notification.

Comment: how is it possible to set it on any given Sound instance?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I had the same question today and figured it out. So maybe this can still help someone down the line.

Here is an example of using the completionhandler in SoundManager from nicklockwood.

If you look at the github code here: https://github.com/nicklockwood/SoundManager/blob/master/SoundManager/SoundManager.m#L51, you'll notice that there is actually a Sound interface in addition to the SoundManager. The completion handler lives on the Sound object, and the SoundManager playSound methods can take either a string file name or the sound object itself. In order to use the completion handler block, we need to use the sound object. (Remember to import `SoundManager.h`)

This is how you do it:

```
Sound *sound = [Sound soundNamed:@"quack.caf"];
sound.completionHandler = ^(BOOL didFinish) {
    if (didFinish) {
        NSLog(@"sound finished");
    }
};
[[SoundManager shareInstance] playSound:sound];
```